# Is a fly-by tower legal for civilians not during a show?

Tags: air-traffic-control

Suppose a civilian wants to fly-by tower in a small plane, like a Cessna 172, would it be legal for him to do it?

I assume here that if it is legal he still would need to ask permission from the ATC.

The region in place would be USA and the European Union.

Comment: This would almost undoubtedly be considered reckless by the pilot. "Buzzing" the tower is something that happens in the movies, in real life it would be met with a license revocation.

Comment: It happens, it's not legal, but I've seen it happen even at a large international airport with helicopters and jets. Albeit not as close as in movies (at the international airport)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not legal.

> 4.6 Except when necessary for take-off or landing, or except by permission from the appropriate authority, a VFR flight shall not be flown: [...] at a height less than 150 m (500 ft) above the ground or water.

*(ICAO Annex 2)*

So unless you are taking off or landing (which you are obviously not, if you are right next to the tower), you are not allowed to fly below 500 feet - and control towers are not 500 feet high.

(The quoted rule is for VFR flights, which I consider to be on topic since you are asking about "a small plane, like a Cessna 172". Similar rules exist for IFR flights, but those are even stricter)

Comment: Does the 4.6 rule is applied only in the vicinity of the airport, or basically everywhere?

Comment: @JohnMayne Basically everywhere, although the FAA has a more relaxed view in that [FAR 91.119(d)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.119) states that I can fly an aircraft at any altitude over an "other than congested area" so long as that I'm not less than 500' to any person, vessel, vehicle, or structure and that I'm at an altitude if my powerplant fails, I can make a landing without undue hazard to persons or property on the surface. Basically I could fly at 20' over the salt flats as long as I'm 500' from anything.

Comment: @Ron Beyer: Not at all uncommon to do that out around  Black Rock or other salt flats.

Comment: I was once flying a Bonanza and was unable to confirm gear down due to a mechanical problem. I reported the problem to the tower and they gave me permission to do a banana pass by the tower. They were able to visually confirm that my gear was down. (The plane had just had an annual and the mechanics left the mechanical gear indicators disconnected!)

Answer (score 1):

Well under normal circumstances the answer is no and a circus stunt like that would be likely to cost you your license, dependant upon how strongly the FAA ASD wanted to pursue it under §91.13 Careless and Reckless Operation.

While buzzing a tower is frowned upon, pilots will sometime make low approaches over a runway as a kind of go-around maneuver.  General etiquette suggests making the maneuver at or above 500 ft AGL, but I've seen plenty of pilots make much lower passes over a runway at untowered airports.

Now on special occasions e.g. motion picture filming, airshow, and aerobatic demonstration flights, waivers can be obtained to make low altitude fly-bys pursuant to the terms of §91.905.  Waivers contains a specific scope and limitations upon which maneuvers may be conducted and on what days and times.  Written proposals for said maneuvers must be submitted for approval in writing to the responsible FSDO.